# Java calling object in method outside of main

Tags: java, variables, object, syntax

I have a simple problem that I've been stuck on for some time and I can't quite find the answer to.  Basically, I'm creating an object and trying to access the variables without using static variables as I was told that is the wrong way to do it.  Here is some example code of the problem.  I receive an error in the first class that can not be resolved to a variable.  What I would like to be able to do is access `t.name` in other methods outside of the main, but also in other classes as well.  To get around this previously I would use `Test2.name` and make the variable static in the `Test2` class, and correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that's the wrong way to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test2 t = new Test2("Joe");         
  }

  public void displayName() {
    System.out.println("Name2: " + t.name);
  }
}

public class Test2 {
  String name;

  public Test2 (String nm) {
    name = nm;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is adding accessor methods in Test2 an option? Like `getName()` method that will return **name**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see others have posted code snippets, but they haven't actually posted why any of this works (at the time of this writing.)

The reason you are getting a compilation error, is that in your method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test2 t = new Test2("Joe");         
}
```

Variable t's scope is just that method. You are defining `Test2 t` to only be in the `main(String[] args)` method, so you can only use the variable `t` in that method. However, if you were to make the variable a field, like so, and create a new instance of the Test class,

```
public class Test {
Test2 t;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.t = new Test2("Joe");  
   test.displayName();
}

public void displayName() {
    System.out.println("Name2: " + t.name);
}
}
```

Then you should no longer be getting any compilation errors, since you are declaring the variable t to be in the class `Test` scope.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  If I wanted to use the variable in a 3rd class, would the code be the same?

Comment: @Jarod it all depends on what the 3rd class is and how you use it. But the basic syntax and idea behind it will still be the same.

Comment: Great, I believe that should solve my problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You may give the reference to your test object as an argument to method `displayName`:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Test2 t = new Test2("Joe");         
        displayName(t);
    }

    public static void displayName(Test2 test) {
        System.out.println("Name2: " + test.name);
    }
}
```

Note: I also made `displayName` a static method. From within your `main` method you can only access static methods without reference.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Test class to this

```
public class Test {
  private static Test2 t;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    t = new Test2("Joe");         
  }

  public void displayName() {
    System.out.println("Name2: " + t.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `getter` for your purpose. This is a side solution to your problem, but generally this is how you should retrieve instance variables, using `getter`s.

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test2 t = new Test2("Joe");         
    displayName(t);
}

public static void displayName(Test2 test) {
    System.out.println(test.getName());
}
}



public class Test2 
{
private String name;

public Test2 (String nm)
{
    name = nm;
}   

public String getName()
{
     return name;
}
}
```

Always remember, variables in your class should be `private`. That protects it from access from outside the class. Hence, `getter`s are the only way to access them. And `setter`s or `constructor`s to initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

Fewer statics the better I reckon.
I would Instantiate Test and call displayName on the instance of it, then pass the instance of Test2 to displayName. 
But it does depend on what the overall aim is

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you say the fewer statics the better?

Comment: Static methods prevent method overriding, so limit subclassing. Static member variables don't play well with serialization. Statics tend to create confusion and code smells (somewhat hacky code) in my experience. Static declarations I personally try to limit to defining constants.